# Why is this code giving me blank page?

Tags: javascript

1. Please Explain what `parseInt` does ?
2. I don't want any function call to execute the code.

   ```
   <html> 
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   <script>
   var a= parseInt(promt("Enter the number"));   
   var b= parseInt(promt("Enter another numbe`enter code here`r"));
   function addition(param1, param2)
   {
   var total =param1+param2;
   return total;
   }
   var result = addition(a,b);
   document.write(result);
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: `prompt` is misspelled as `promt`. Your code is throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

The page is blank because of the errors in your code. It's preventing the `document.write` from running.

1) `parseInt` changes a string to an integer(number).

2) Not sure what you mean by this question. If you simply mean you want the code to run in sequence without being inside a function, this will work:

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number"));
var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter another number"));
var total = a+b;
document.write(total);
```

Also, `prompt` has been mispelled as `promt` which won't work. This is the error preventing your code from successfully writing to the page (Thanks, Joe Clay)

Answer (score -1):

1) parseInt changes the string to an integer.

You made a mistake: 'promt' must be replaced by 'prompt'.